# Comment never put into an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I had an answer to my question in a comment, but the author never put it as an answer?  I tried to reach him via chat with no success.

What do I do now?  I want him to get the credit for the answer, but it's still a comment and I don't know the right way to contact him?  Does this need to be a feature for the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the poster of the comment hasn't replied/converted the comment to an answer after a "few" days (where the value of a "few" depends on all sorts of things) then you are free to post it as an answer yourself.

If you feel bad about getting reputation from someone else's work then mark the answer as Community Wiki and reference the comment and poster.

In fact there's nothing stopping someone else posting it as an answer either, so get in there quick before someone else does :)

Comment: Thank you Chris!  Yes, in keeping with all the good camaraderie here, I don't want to steal someones points.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard Don't forget, you'll get notified if the user does post his comment as an answer eventually, so you can always un-accept your own answer and accept his to give him the points